# Login submit OOP not working in bootstrap form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, oop

I have a bootstrap login form for an admin user that has a login submit button, but when I press it, nothing happens.
Here's the html form placed in a login form template loginForm.php

```
  <form action="admin.php?action=login" method="post" style="width: 50%;">
    <input type="hidden" name="login" value="true" />

    <?php if ( isset( $results['errorMessage'] ) ) { ?>
       <div class="errorMessage"><?php echo $results['errorMessage'] ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="field-wrap">
        <label for="username">
          username<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label for="password">
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="login" class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

  </form>
```

and here's the login() function in the admin.php which includes all the functions for the admin.

```
function login() {

 $results = array();
 $results['pageTitle'] = "Admin Login | Malang Foodies";

 if ( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) {

   // User has posted the login form: attempt to log the user in

   if ( $_POST['username'] == ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] == ADMIN_PASSWORD ) {

     // Login successful: Create a session and redirect to the admin homepage
     $_SESSION['username'] = ADMIN_USERNAME;
     header( "Location: admin.php" );

   } else {

     // Login failed: display an error message to the user
     $results['errorMessage'] = "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.";
     require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
   }

 } else {

   // User has not posted the login form yet: display the form
   require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
 }
}
```

Well, to be clear, all the functions that include a submit button like addArticle(), editArticle() in the admin.php does not work anymore when I adapted the bootstrap template, because before adapting bootstrap all the functions work fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, you have no field/button called `login`, so `isset($_POST['login'])` will never be true (only `btn-login`)

Comment: Yeah, forgot to change the submit button name to just "login". But it still does not work..

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` - do you see something unexpected?

Comment: where do I add that?

Comment: instead of checking for isset($_POST['login']), try count($_POST). I think your issue is because you're never actually submitting the form at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spurious forward slash / character in the button markup, so effectively you've closed the button tag twice:

```
<button type="submit" name="login" class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>
```

because you have: `<button.... />` (the spurious / character which closes some other tags, so it's probably throwing the browser completely). Delete that and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

He does have an input "login". It's the first of the form and it's hidden.
Is ADMIN_USERNAME and ADMIN_PASSWORD defined somewhere?
Or are you sure you sure both password and username match the constants?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the config.php which is required in the admin.php

Comment: And they match?
And what do you mean by "but when I press it, nothing happens" ?

Comment: I inserted the correct username and password, then I clicked the login button, then nothing happens it just stays in the login form page, does not load or anything..

Comment: Try with the button: <button type="submit" name="login" class="button button-block">Log In</button>. Note the closing tag.

Comment: Your PHP code woking here: https://eval.in/484066. If you change the user/password you'll see it does what you are expecting.
Maybe you are really never submitting your form.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that this is a PHP issue? Try putting a statement like die('here') somewhere in the checking of POST values. I suspect, because your form is a button, the form isn't actually submitting. You might want to check for javascript errors on the page.